# Default selection in bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap dropdown, and need to have the first option as default. The following doesn't work.

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    CHOOSE FEATURE
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>

<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li selected="selected"><a>Feature 1</a></li>
    <li><a>Feature 2</a></li>
    <li><a>Feature 3</a></li>
    <li><a>Feature 4</a></li>
    <li><a>Feature 5</a></li>
    <li><a>Feature 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474857/select-default-value-in-drop-down-bootstrap-3

Comment: see answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437446/how-to-display-selected-item-in-bootstrap-button-dropdown-title

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe you'll be able to achieve this effect using a conventional bootstrap drop down menu.

Unlike a traditional HTML "select", a bootstrap drop down is typically used to group a series of links under a header. When you click a menu item, it doesn't become selected as such, rather an action is usually performed.

I'd advise just using a straightforward HTML select, but borrowing styles from the bootstrap CSS library so it looks consistent. Something along the lines of:

```
<select class="bootstrap-select">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Feature 1</option>
  <option value="2">Feature 2</option>
  <option value="3">Feature 3</option>
  <option value="4">Feature 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like this is the best option. I used css styling from the following to approach that of bootstrap:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript    and     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542576/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-the-list-not-the-initial-view

Comment: This doesn't answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $(".dropdown .dropdown-menu li a")[0].click();
});
```

This will always select your first `li`

Answer (score 1):

The attribute "selected" only works in `<select>` elements. Unfortunately it does not work in lists.

I believe what you want is:

```
<select class="form-control" name="features">
    <option value="" selected>Feature 1</option>
    <option value="">Feature 2</option>
    <option value="">Feature 3</option>
    <option value="">Feature 4</option>
    <option value="">Feature 5</option>
    <option value="">Feature 6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: nice, `form-control` worked!

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this with `Flask` + `Python` + `Jinja` stack this way, if you have a different back end the same logic could still apply. Use an if statement to check if the value is the one you wanted, and if it is, set it as selected. In my instance I'm setting the topic to ZTM-Linux below.

```
        <select class="form-control" id="Topic" name="Topic">
            <option disabled>Choose a Topic</option>
            {% for each in query %}
            <option value="{{ each.topic }}" {% if each.topic == "ZTM-Linux" %}selected{% endif %}>{{ each.topic }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <?php //your loop start here{ ?>
        <a id="some_id" class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <?php echo $yourvalue ?> </a>
    <?php //your loop end here  } ?>
  </div>
</div>

  .....

</html>

<script>                                                         
    $(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#some_id")[0].click();
     });
 </script>
```